# How to run two minecraft servers with kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm researching how to deploy a game server with kubernetes, but am running into an issue with having the pods running the game be accessible to the web without a LoadBalancer. Since running a load balancer for each pod is not an option I was told to use ingress with nodeports to make them available over the web.

I am able to get the cluster created and the pods all distributed onto the nodes the way I want them, I am unable to make them accessible though. I created a [github repo](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/minecraft_docker/tree/master/k8s/prod-azure#then-lets-set-up-helm-ingress-nginx), link is to the kubernetes section, that has all the code to run the server locally if you want to test it. As for running the project in the cloud though I can't seem to get that to work. In the Readme I have the steps I went through and the files with the code I have so far. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Am I missing a file or some conceptual idea that is going over my head with the nodeports setup?

Answer (score 3):

I found that I needed to use ClusterIP instead of NodePort. I also found that I needed to patch not just the ingress deployment but I also needed to patch the ingress service to include the tcp-services data ports I was saying were available in the Ingress deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Your README.md shows the command used to create your node pool as:

```
az aks nodepool add --resource-group mwK8ResourceGroup --cluster-name cluster-1 --name gamenodepool --node-count 2 --kubernetes-version 1.15.7 --labels "workload=game-selector" --node-taints "key1=value1:NoExecute" --node-osdisk-size 30 --node-vm-size Standard_DS2_v2 --debug
```

When setting up a NodePort type of service, the service is exposed by accessing the node directly via a IP address. I would expect that your create command would include `--enable-node-public-ip` for your sample code to work as-is.

Please refer to this section of the kubernetes docs for details: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-the-service

You can also run a separate load balancer that forwards traffic to each/either node on the port that is exposed by the NodePort service(s).

If you exposed the service using an "Ingress" resource, you would access the service via the cluster IP address rather than the individual node's IP address.

Comment: When you say clusterIP do you mean the ingress controller address? Every pod has its own clusterIP

Comment: --enable-node-public-ip is not an option now, I assume the Microsoft docs are outdated.

Comment: @mjwrazon - "cluster IP" would be the public load balancer that points to your cluster. The NodePort service should be accessible from the individual node. Have you seen these diagrams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#services

Comment: I am trying to make each individual pod reachable externally, each pod is on its own node. Neither clusterIP or NodePort allow this. Not on Azure anyway. @bpdohall

Comment: @mjwrazor - it sounds like you are missing a component to bridge the gap between the public internet and your private endpoints. Have you tried setting up an Azure load balancer to expose your endpoints?

Comment: If you read my initial question you will see I am working to avoid a load balancer for each since I have already gotten that to work but wan to avoid the costs and limitations. I am working to use an Ingress and originally asking for help on that. @bpdohall

Comment: Seems like my understanding of the question shifted as we went back and forth. I initially thought you wanted to avoid having a load balancer entirely. Glad you've got it sorted out. Cheers!

Comment: For reference, you can also connect your Ingress resource to a NodePort service using the service name, as shown in this example: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45438#issuecomment-301214982